# Why is my Spaces and actual game not printing correctly

Tags: python

My game almost works perfectly but for some reason my space variable wont print correctly.
Also, the game automatically asks to play again after pressing enter. My code runs fine it s just not printing what I want it to print. The only problems are with the `Spaces` variable and maybe somewhere in 1 of the functions.

```
import random

HANGMANPICS = ['''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========''']
words={
    'Colors':'red orange yellow green blue indigo violet white black brown'.split(),
    'Shapes':'square triangle rectangle circle ellipse rhombus trapezoid chevron pentagon hexagon septagon octagon'.split(),
    'Fruits':'apple orange lemon lime pear watermelon grape grapefruit cherry banana cantaloupe mango strawberry tomato'.split(),
    'Animals':'bat bear beaver cat cougar crab deer dog donkey duck eagle fish frog goat leech lion lizard monkey moose mouse otter owl panda python rabbit rat shark sheep skunk squid tiger turkey turtle weasel whale wolf wombat zebra'.split()}
def getRandomWord(wordDict):
    # This function returns a random string from the passed dictionary of lists of strings, and the key also.
    # First, randomly select a key from the dictionary:
    wordKey = random.choice(list(wordDict.keys()))
    # Second, randomly select a word from the key's list in the dictionary:
    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordDict[wordKey]) - 1)
    return [wordDict[wordKey][wordIndex], wordKey]
    
    
def displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print(HANGMANPICS[len(missedLetters)])
    print()

    print(' Missed letters:', end=' ')
    for letter in missedLetters:
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

    spaces = '_' * len(secretWord)

    for i in range(len(secretWord)): # replace blanks with correctly guessed letters
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            spaces = spaces[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in spaces: # show the secret word with spaces in between each letter
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()
    
def GetdaGuess(alreadyGuessed):
    while True:
        print('Pick a letter for the Hangman Game')
        R_I = input()
        R_I = R_I.lower()
        if len(R_I) != 1:
            print('Please enter 1 letter only')
        elif R_I in alreadyGuessed:
            print('You"ve chosen that letter. Please try again')
        if R_I not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print('Only letters please')
        return R_I
        
def Play1MoreTime():
    guess = input('Would you like to play again?\n')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')

print('H A N G M A N ')
missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWords = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False

while True:
    displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWords)

    guess = GetdaGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

    if guess in secretWords:
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess


    foundAllDaLetters = True
    for i in range(len(secretWords)):
        if secretWords[i] not in correctLetters:
            foundAllDaLetters = False
            break
    if foundAllDaLetters:
        print('Good job. The correct word was'+ secretWord+'. ')
    
    if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:

        print('Your out of tries.\nAfter ' + str(len(missedLetters)) + ' wrong guesses and ' + str(len(correctLetters)) + ' correct guesses, the word was "' + secretWord + '"')

    gameIsDone = True


    
    if gameIsDone:
        if  Play1MoreTime():
            missedLetters = ''
            correctLetters = ''
            gameIsdone = False
            secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: `my space variable wont print correctly` how so? Please give an example. Also, please show an example output that demonstrates `the game automatically asks to play again after pressing enter`. We shouldn't have to run your code to understand what the problems precisely are. And you need to also show an example of what the expected output and behavior should be in both cases.

Comment: Please add to your question what's the desired output and what's the actual output.

As far as I can see 'spaces' is printed in a reasonable manner...

Comment: The spaces are supposed to be the length of the secret word. it is only printing 2 every time I run it

Comment: @python that kinda half-answered one of my questions. If you want help you'll have to actually read our comments and not just skip over the important stuff we're asking and telling you. It's kind of rude to just ignore us like that. If you don't understand what we're asking or telling you, then don't just ignore the parts you don't understand.